# How do you turn on Production mode for Redux Toolkit in the browser?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit

I really am loving the Redux Toolkit, but it has some warnings that I know I can safely ignore (non-serializable values in an action being sent to some thunks; in this case an API) but I want to make sure they do not show up in the shipped application.

I can't seem to find how to turn on production mode which would skip the "serializable-state-invariant-middleware" when I deploy a finished version to the browser. I know I could modify the list of middleware to avoid it, but that seems really clunky.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the creator and maintainer of Redux Toolkit.

Like most libraries in the NPM ecosystem, production mode is detected based on `process.env.NODE_ENV` being set to `'production'`.  This happens automatically in most build tools, such as Webpack's `mode: 'production'`

Create-React-App and other meta-build frameworks also ensure this is set automatically, so you shouldn't have to worry about it.

You can [review the contents of a production bundle using `source-map-explorer`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/analyzing-the-bundle-size) to help confirm that it's behaving as expected.

(Also, note that the "non-serializable values in actions" message with `createAsyncThunk` is [a bug that we will be fixing shortly](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/453).)

Comment: I do not always have a build process. I use Snowpack to generate a JS module version of the few packages I need and then I just load what I need via ES6.

I was just looking for a mechanism to turn off warning messages that wouldn't normally be shown in "production".

Comment: Yeah, then you're pretty much on your own.  Like I said, use of `process.env.NODE_ENV='production'` is the common convention for packages published to NPM, and [then bundlers and optimizers process that at build time to strip out the dead code](https://overreacted.io/how-does-the-development-mode-work/).  No idea what the equivalent is for Snowpack.